# Pass and return Variable in different Workbook Module

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference

I can't return a changed Variable from a differenten Module in another Workbook.

Workbook A:

```
Dim A As String
Dim B As String
Dim C As String
Dim D As String

A = "A"
B = "B"
C = "C"

 Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\two.xlsm"

Application.Run "'two.xlsm'!test_her", A, B, C, D

Debug.Print A, B, C, D

End Sub
```

Workbook B:

```
Public B
Public D

Public Sub test_her(ByRef A As String, ByVal B As String, C As String, ByRef D As String)


A = A & "TEST"
B = B & "TEST"
C = C & "TEST"
D = "CHANGED"

End Sub
```

It works that the variables can be passed to "test_her" and processed. But I haven't figured out how to pass them back modified?

If I work in the same workbook it works with the public variables, only in different workbooks I can't pass them.

Comment: be careful - you have `Public B` (as variant) and a `ByVal B as string` in the same module. If not necessary, I would remove the public B and use `ByRef B as string` as parameter - passing it ByVal won't return it to the calling routine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a quick search, it looks like the solution is to assign the Application object to an object variable, and then call the Run method from that variable.

```
Sub test()

Dim A As String
Dim B As String
Dim C As String
Dim D As String

A = "A"
B = "B"
C = "C"

 Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\two.xlsm"
        
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = Application

xlApp.Run "'two.xlsm'!test_her", A, B, C, D

End Sub
```